# How many candidate keys are there in the table shown below?

Tags: database-theory, databases

One candidate key is (report_no, author_id).
What are the other candidate keys?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? If you know what a candidate key is, what's stopping you from identifying them?

Comment: Can we apply the concept of candidate key in an unnormalized table?

Answer (score 0):

"We have to consider all the relations that might be assigned to a relvar to determine whether a certain set of attributes is a candidate key. ... However, we might be able to conclude from such a relation that a certain set is not a candidate key, " as it says in [the first place I looked](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key)

"The set of all candidate keys can be computed e.g. from the set of functional dependencies. "

So are you told the functional dependencies for this table? Or anything about the meaning or structure of the contents?

I notice looking at just columns `{report_no, editor, dept_no, dept_name, dept_address}`, the first three rows of the table have same content; rows 4 to 6 have the same content. Is that an accident, or a consequence of the structure?

*If* `{report_no, author_id}` is a CK (how are you determining that?), then it's looking like any one of those columns with `author_id` could be a CK.

Similarly, looking at this content the columns `{author_id, author_name, author_addr}` show a pattern. Perhaps there's a functional dependency? It's looking like `author_name` with any one of the 5 left columns could be a CK.

There's only one column that definitely can't be an element of a candidate key, going by this content. That's `author_addr`: look at the rows with `author_addr = mathrev`. There's no pattern of content in other columns for those rows.

I notice the table is labelled "(1NF)". I'd take that as a hint to find out about 2NF, 3NF.

Answer (score -1):

One candidate key is (report_no, author_id).

It can uniquely determine a row in the REPORT table shown above.

Second candidate key is (dept_no, author_id).

It can also uniquely determine a row in the REPORT table shown above.